# How to skip or disable displaying crash message box in Win7

Tags: .net, unit-testing, windows-7, coded-ui-tests

I'm developing and running Coded UI automated tests on virtual machines. 
The process that executes the UI automation is QTAgent32_40.exe
Occasionally (quite rarely) - QTAgent crashes, for unknown (at the moment) reason. 
The problem is that test is stuck forever until I close the error message, and any further tests do not run. 
I get this message - tried to look into stack trace - nothing useful:
[image: Windows reporting error]

I googled a bit, and tried to disable the windows error reporting service, now the message is different: 
[image: Generic error message]

I would like to disable or close the message somehow - so that the Agent could restart and continue. 
I've read all the questions about QTAgent - but could not find solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have no control ober QTAgent32.exe, you just start it using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("QTAgent32.exe");
```

(or something similar) and wait for it to complete.

In that case, you could use a timeout and just kill it if it doesn't want to exit peacefully:

```
var process = Process.Start("QTAgent32.exe");
Thread.Sleep(60000); // Wait for one minute
if (!process.HasExited)
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Edit: You could of course use polling, meaning a loop containing shorter wait times and checking if the process has exited, instead of always waiting for a minute.